# change file extension when user quite the page

Tags: php, jquery

i have a page,called for example, test.html,i want to change it for example to test.php, when the user leaves the pages, is there a way to do so?

i know how to change it with php using rename..But how to call that when the user leave the page?

Comment: Please show what have you tried so far...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that comes to my mind is using the beforeunload event, triggered before the browser unloads the page to render another one, make an ajax call and let php do the rest.

jQuery:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    $.post(
        'rename-file.php', 
        {file: "this.html"}
    ).done(response) {
        console.log('Response: ' + response);
    }
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
$oldname = $_POST['file'];
$newname = str_replace('.html', '.php', $oldname);

if(rename ( $oldname , $newname )) {
   echo 'File renamed successfully';
} else {
   echo 'File could not be renamed';
}
```

Will it work? It's something that has to be seen...

The onbeforeunload event might not work in all browsers, that's one of the downsides.

Other thing you have to think of is: Is this really necessary? To rename the same page I'm using to another extension knowing that the renaming process might be impossible due to the server using that file for rendering.

And last but not least, security, the above code is just a basic example, but remember that security is the key to happiness.

Comment: I don't think `beforeunload` is allowed to use AJAX.

Comment: It is, I use it in one of my applications and it works :P